# Expanding physical quantities in dimensionless parameters

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I have a system with two dimensionful parameters, say, chemical potential ($ \mu $) and temperature ($ T $). Now I want to write down an ansatz for any physical quantity (e.g, Greens function) at small or high frequency ($\omega$). What should be my relevant dimensionless expansion parameters?

EDIT:

To clarify the situation let me give you a simpler example : suppose there is only one dimensionful parameter, $T$. In this case for small frequency I can expand any physical quantity as a perturbation in $\omega \over T$.

Comment: I think to be answerable this needs edits with a good deal more detail about what  you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I have added a simpler example. Hopefully that will be useful.

Comment: Isn't that the point of dimensional analysis via [the Buckingham $\pi$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, dimensional analysis tells you that you can only generalize a pure/arbitrary function to parameters which are dimensionless; hence if in your system you have three things, $\omega$, $\mu$, and $T$ with the dimension of energy, things must be a function of:$$f\left({\omega\over\mu},{\omega\over T}\right)$$Notice that $\mu/T$ is redundant ($f(x, y) = y/x$) so you have some freedom here. You then find the Taylor multinomial of $f$ for the regime you're interested in and truncate it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Physically I can tune $T$ or $\mu$. So $T \over \mu$ should appear somewhere. I am a bit confused.

Comment: I guess my confusion is : can I also expand the function in {$\omega \over T$, $\mu \over T$} or {$\omega \over \mu$, $T \over \mu$}?

Comment: @pinu Yes, but you may not have the condition $\mu/T \gg 1$ or $\mu/T \ll 1$ so you don't necessarily have the logical-reasoning you need to cut off the Taylor multinomial for $f$.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly I can expand $f$ in {$ \omega \over T$, $\mu \over T $} for large $T$ and  in {$ \omega \over \mu$, $T \over \mu $} for large $ \mu $. Physically high or low temperature expansions..

Comment: As always when Taylor-expanding, include terms up to one more order than you think you need to confirm that they can in fact be neglected in your result: but yes, that's basically what I'm saying.